# hadoop connection refused when trying to connect to datanode

Tags: hadoop

There are 2 nodes cluster just created in hadoop. I am able to connect to master and run MR jobs but unable to connect to slave is that fine?. So i understand that namenode is not running in slave so started the node fully so that when i do a `jps` i see

```
2287 TaskTracker
2149 JobTracker
1938 DataNode
2085 SecondaryNameNode
2349 Jps
1788 NameNode
```

Now i can connect to slave and work as i do with master but 2 namenodes exists then it sounds something fishy, but i could be wrong. Kindly suggest.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about small experimental clusters, you should only have one namenode (the master node). You can have any amount of datanodes - the master can also be one of them. You have to be able to connect from the master to the slaves (datanodes) with SSH without a password.

When you run MR jobs, you should check the namenode web interface to see how the job is distributed. If all of your nodes are used (for some of the jobs at least), then the setup is working.

Comment: But other than Datanode should anything else be running in slave to run MR jobs or connecting to slave? or is my understanding wrong that we can connect to slave?

Comment: Slave should have DataNode and NodeManager running. But Hadoop should take care of starting the right processes when you start the cluster from the master node.

Comment: so how can i let master know that it has to start NodeManager on slave

Comment: Simply but adding the slave node to the file `slaves`

Comment: i have done that but i see only DataNode starting and that is what i also see in the michael-noll article also.

Comment: Well I am not 100% sure that the nodemanager needs to be running on slaves. That's just how it is with my setup.
Do you still have the original problem? What process can't connect to the slaves? What are the error messages?

Comment: The issue is i am not able to understand how MR jobs can run on slave when no task tracker is running. Just the DataNode is up also as you previously said when i see the http://server:50070/dfshealth.html i see last contact keeps varing meaning MR jobs are running.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I guess you are using an older version of Hadoop. NodeManager might be a process that's only in the newer versions - I'm not sure what the required processes are in the old version.

Comment: i am using 2.4.1 is it old :). But am not using yarn to run MR jobs. Does it make a difference?

Comment: You shouldn't have a TaskTracker or JobTracker in 2.4.1. Check http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/

Comment: thats correct so how is the MR jobs running on slave and why is that am unable to connect to slave node using the HDFS client code

Comment: Fix your setup. As I said, you have processes running that you shouldn't have.